# Testing an Ethernet peripheral

Tags: ethernet, stm32, production-testing

I have an Ethernet peripheral (manual [here](http://www.smsc.com/media/Downloads_Public/Data_Sheets/8710a.pdf)) controlled by an STM32. I have to test that the Ethernet peripheral works correctly right after the board is manufactured. Conveniently, there are three "loopback" modes for testing. (See page 41: near-end, far and connector loopback.)

I wonder if using these three loopback testing modes (doing basic I/O) is sufficient to guaranty that the Ethernet peripheral will work properly in production.

Are there non-loopback tests that I should consider to test the integrity and functionality of my Ethernet peripheral?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I basically just plug it in and have it do a request, make sure the data gets through OK.

Test heavy data transfers (or at least as heavy as the design will be rated to handle), try as many different hubs/switches as you can (10, 10/100, Gbit, etc). Try different duplexes, etc.

In my experience, if the design is sound and one unit verifies OK, the hardware is not the likely point of failure - issues are more likely to crop up in the TCP/IP stack or application code.